# Passing values to webmethod using Json

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I am having trouble sending values to my webmethod using JSON.

```
public class Order
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string SendOrder(string name, string branch, string jobFunction, string requestReason, string logo, string json)
{
    var orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(json);
}
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
$('#SubmitOrder').on('click', function (e) {

    var table = $('#orders-table').tableToJSON({
        ignoreColumns: [4]
    });

    var obj = {
        Name: $('#FullNametbx').val(),
        Branch: $('#Address').val(),
        JobFunction: $('#JobFunction').val(),
        RequestReason: $('#RequestReason').val(),
        Logo: $('#LogoOnShirt').val(),
        Orders: table
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Apparel.aspx/SendOrder",
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(obj) },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what I get with Fiddler:

```
{ 
  'name': 'Roger Rabbit', 
  'branch': 'PHX', 
  'jobfunction': 'Service Tech',
  'requestReason': 'New Hire',
  'logo': 'Nike',
  'json': '[
    {
      "Item":"Port Authority Women's Jacket #L790 - Black",
      "Size":"X-Small",
      "Color":"Black",
      "Quantity":"3"
    },
    {
      "Item":"Port Authority® Long Sleeve Easy Care Shirt",
      "Size":"3XL-Tall",
      "Color":"Black",
      "Quantity":"4"
    }]'
}
```

The issue is that I have all of the basic parameters as strings but the last parameter is called "json" and that is a list of orders which are in an html table and I call a stringify on the table so I think that is coming back with a bad result.

How can I change my ajax call to pass the correct values to the correct parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Web method to accept the object

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendOrder(IEnumerable<Order> order)
{
    //No need to deserialize the JSON
}
```

You can lose the json property on your Order class too.

Also pop a `dataType: "json"` into your jQuery AJAX call.

If you need to retain your parameters then create another class composed of these and the `Order` class, then pull them out inside your WebMethod.

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ... etc ... //
}
```

Change your AJAX to this rather than concatenating the string yourself:

```
var obj = {
    "name" : $('#FullNametbx').val(),
    "branch" : $('#Address').val(),
    "jobfunction" : $('#JobFunction').val()
    // ... etc ... //
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Apparel.aspx/SendOrder",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue with that is that there is actually 2 orders so I would need List<Order>()

Comment: i need the other paramters as well. Will I be able to keep those?

Comment: What will my ajax call look like?

Comment: I would avoid building the string yourself. Construct an object in JS and stringify it instead. See the example I've added.

Comment: I will need to make the parameter the ViewModel right. public static void SendOrder(OrderViewModel model)

Comment: I keep getting the Json error : Invalid Primitive Data.

Comment: Did you add dataType: 'json' to your AJAX call? Also add double-quote to the property names of `obj` as shown in my update.

Comment: I got it to work by changing my webmethod to     public static void SendOrder(string Name, string Branch, string JobFunction, string RequestReason, string Logo, Order[] Orders)
    {}. I think there might be an issue with passing the object using .NET 2

Comment: I'm surprised it even works in .NET 2! Anyway glad you sorted it and thanks for accepting the answer.